# Drools vs DDD: Does Drools require Flat Object Models?

Tags: domain-driven-design, drools, object-model

In our e-commerce domain, we have a hierarchy of entities that are modeled using nested arrays.  We do this using the principles of Domain-Driven Design (as explained by Eric Evans).  The central concepts in our e-commerce domain are:

- *Contracts*, which HAVE *Exchanges*, each of which HAS both *Services* and *Payments*.  Services, in turn, HAVE *Features* that describe each service.

This hierarchical model enables us to express any contract, no matter how complex, including those that have multiple agreements (that is, Exchanges) as part of the overall agreement (or, Contract).

Does Drools not support such hierarchical object models?  Should I invert my object model to a flat object model with no arrays (like the "Fires HAVE Rooms" & "Sprinklers HAVE Rooms" [example in the Drools Expert documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.5.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e737)) as follows?

- *Contracts*.
- *Exchanges*, each of which HAS a single Contract.
- *Services* and *Payments*, each of which HAS a single Exchange.
- *Features*, each of which HAS a single Service.

Am I right that inverting hierarchical object models in this way, into flat object models with atomic assertions, is what is supported and works best in Drools?  Drools doesn't appear to support a rule with LHS conditions on a fact and a fact that is in a subcollection.

If so, why doesn't Drools support more hierarchical object models?  Is it because Drools comes from the AI world (not the object-oriented world) in which First-Order Logic expresses all facts as atomic subject-predicate-value statements, and not the object-oriented world in which entity objects have identity, value objects don't have identity, and entity objects are composed of other entity and value objects?

Answer (score 1):

You can define rules against any Java object model.

The documentation provides examples based on toy problems to avoid distraction from what it's explaining. Not because Drools is incapable of dealing with more complex models. If you read a bit further through the manual, you will see examples for dealing with lists using syntax such as 'contains' or accumulators.

It's up to you how you model this. You can insert Contracts, Exchanges, Services, Payments and Features as separate facts, which reference each other. Alternatively, you could just insert a complex Contract fact, which contains lists of Exchanges, which contain lists of Services, etc.

Which works better for you depends on whether your rules match on a Contract with very little chaining, or whether you want a rule to react to something such as a change in a Feature, or the insertion of a Payment fact.

Answer (score 0):

Nested accessors on objects is supported, as Drools works with any Pojo. However there is no reactivity on nested accessors.

It is possible, as a feature request, to start adding nested accessor reactivity, by inserting listeners. It's a non trivial piece of work, but it would be very interesting.